# If $G_1$ and $G_2$ are open subset of [a,b] then $|G_1|+|G_2|=|G_1 \cup G_2|+|G_1 \cap G_2|$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $G_1$ and $G_2$ are open subset of [a,b] then $|G_1|+|G_2|=|G_1 \cup G_2|+|G_1 \cap G_2|$
I have some problem to understand complete theorem.
in this theorem first case is finitely many intervals reference book using $\chi$ function which have 4 cases.whenever $x \in  [a,b]$ then they will directly say that $\chi$ function is Riemann integrable i don't know why?please help me.thanks in advance.

Comment: What does $|G|$ mean?

Comment: My answer assumes he means Lebesgue measure or Jordan content.

Comment: yes it is Lebesgue measure.

Comment: It has to be only a measure in a more general way.

Answer (score 2):

First note that
$$G_1\cup G_2 = G_1\cup(G_2 - (G_1\cap G_2).$$
This union is disjoint so

$$|G_1\cup G_2| = |G_1| + |G_2 - (G_1\cap G_2)|.$$

Now suppose we have $B$  and $C$ with $C\subseteq B$.  Then we have the 
disjoint union
$$B = C\cup (B-C). $$
Using finite additivity,
$$|B| = |C| - |B - C|.$$
so
$$|B - C| = |B| -|C|.$$

Apply this principle to see that

$$|G_1 - (G_1\cap G_2)| = |G_2| - |G_1\cap G_2|. $$
Your result follows immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two hints:

- For every sets $A$ and $B$, one has $\mathbf 1_{A\cup B}+\mathbf 1_{A\cap B}=\mathbf 1_{A}+\mathbf 1_{B}$.
- For every subset $A$ of $[a,b]$, one has $|A|=\int\limits_a^b\mathbf 1_{A}$.

The result follows.  Additionally, this method shows that $G_1$ and $G_2$ can be any measurable subsets. (If the question is to know why every open set is measurable, recall that, by definition, the Borel sigma-algebra is generated by the collection of open sets.)